# How to store a backbone.js view and then reuse it again

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a web application using backbone.js. I have two tabs. Tab 1 is a backbone.js view and tab2 is another backbone view (of the same kind).

Both the views are loaded to the same div element in the page. Currently what I do is, when user change the tab, I detect it using the backbone router. Then router does a check to see if a view is already there, or should it be created.

I created a object manager object, who store the view object based on a key (key is the tab name)

```
App.ObjectManager.getContentView = function (tabId) {

    return App.ObjectManager.ContentHash[tabId];
};

App.ObjectManager.setContentView = function(tabId, view) {

    App.ObjectManager.ContentHash[tabId] = view;
};

App.ObjectManager.hasContentView = function(tabId) {

    if(App.ObjectManager.ContentHash[tabId]==undefined) {
        return 0;
    }

    else{
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Here is what I do to create and store the view to list object. This code is called every time a tab is clicked, and router detects the change.

```
$("#myDiv").html(""); 

if(App.ObjectManager.hasContentView(tabId)==0) {  //View is not in the lookup table

    console.log("View is not created yet. So we need to create");
    content = new App.MyBackboneView(); //create a new view
    App.ObjectManager.setContentView(tabId, content); //Store the view
}

else {

    console.log("View is already created..So we read it and show it");
    content = App.ObjectManager.getContentView(tabId);

}

//Now, we add the view to the main div

$("#myDiv").append(content.el);
```

The code above works by showing the view to the myDiv. and I can see the values of text boxes and radio buttons, etc being shown.

The only thing - event handling don't work. So, if I have a button in the view that is added an event handler, the event don't get called when the view is rendered from the saved object. First time when the view gets shown, click event is handling.

For eg, I have this button in the view "Say My Name!"

```
events: {
    "click #say": "sayName"
},

sayName: function() {
    console.log("I click say Name");
}
```

First time the view gets loaded, when I press the button, console show me the log. When I come back to the tab again, and this time view is shown from the list object, the click event don't work.

Is my code having any problem ?

Hope you can give me some way how to store the view and I can reuse the view again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a view you empty myDiv content

```
$("#myDiv").html("");
```

I think this action automatically removes all bindings that you set in your View earlier. It's actually quite a common problem with Backbone - this framework sets event listeners to dom elements in the view.

Probably easiest way to deal with this issue is to create a parent View for #myDiv as a whole and set events in there.

View structure may look like that:

TabsView (set events here)
  |
   - Tab View 1 (render content)
   - Tab View 2 (render content)

Comment: Or $("#myDiv").empty(). Same thing but a little more elegant.

Comment: @TyroneMichael, i too usually use empty() instead of html(''), but since it's a line in the question i don't see the need to modify it.

Comment: Thanks. Cool ! Here is what I did

App.TabMainView = Backbone.View.extend({

 el:"#myDiv",

 events: {
  "click #say": "sayName"
 },
 
 sayName: function() {
  console.log("I click say Name");
 },
 
 initialize:function(){
 console.log("Main TabsView View created");
  
 var content = this.options.model.content;
 $(this.el).append(content.el);
 }
});
and then in the router code, I add 

content = App.ObjectManager.getContentView(tabId);
var model = {content:content};
var tabView = new App.TabMainView({model:model});

Comment: With above code change,  Now, I see the events are enabled. Just that the events are getting stacked up.

i.e., when I click the tab 1, and press the button, it show "I click say Name"
Then, when I go to tab 2, and press the button, it show "I click say Name" twice
and when I come to tab 1 again, and press the button, it show "I click say Name" thrice.

any other thing I should check in the above to handle this multiple handle stacking ?

Comment: @user1402539, check your code, it seems like you're reinitializing TabMainView twice. It should be initialized only once. Did you remove click events from individual tab views?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Here is what I did.      
var tabView;
if(App.TabView==undefined) {

 tabView = new App.TabMainView({model:model});

}
else
{
 tabView = App.TabView;
}

tabView.setContent(content);

App.TabView = tabView;   

I stored the tabView and reused it again. The button click is now working. I did had a one question.

Comment: If I start adding events to the main tabView, will it get complex when I have more dynamic views, or when one view creates multiple views with its own unique ids.

Right now, in my app, one view creates more views, which in turn creates more views based on user behavior. you think tracking all events outside is managable and wont have any event delegation issues ? any best practice you think of that I use ?  thanks !

Comment: @user1402539, depends on how many events you want to handle and how complex inner views are. If you can, bind general events in parent view if you have an inner view that generates list of elements that are generated by element view then bind events to element's parent view and when needed just reinitialize it - if it's not super complex then it'll be displayed as fast as if yoyu just changed css style from display: none to display: block;

Comment: Great. I got it working now. I did event delegation once the event is captured by the parent. I have TabMainView, TabInnerView, and TabLineView.

TabMainView creates TabInnerView. TabInnerView has option to create multiple TabLineView. The event handler to add the new TabLineView is in the parent TabMainView. Once I get the event,
I delegate it to the TabInnerView to perform the actual action. Something like this in the main parent. 

addNewFilterRow : function() {

  console.log("Add row filter pressed");
  this.tabInner.addNewFilterLine();
}

Comment: thus, the event is handled in the outside parent and actual adding the line is done the InnerView. I think this approach is good, as I can catch the event from the myDiv and then delegate it the right view to perform the action.

Thank u for the help ! happy to see the code working !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, I have several "tab views" that show aggregated data, something like "my messages", "all messages", "all users" etc. I store views' objects in a hash, say 'views'.

Yes, indeed as Kane Cohen has mentioned:

```
$('#myDiv').html('') or $('#myDiv').$el.empty()
```

destroys all bindings... What worked for me is rather using "detach" as it doesn't destroy bindings (http://api.jquery.com/detach/), suppose previous displayed content was 'All messages', and user clicks on 'My messages':

```
views['All messages'].$el.detach()
$('#myDiv').append views['My messages'].el
```

*I use coffescript...*
P.s. Hope this helps, allthough I'm not satisfied with this approach...

Comment: You should post this as a new question, rather than an answer to an old question